# How to extends HashMap to allow String, String types

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to create a custom class that extends java.util.LinkedHashMap and takes String as key and String as value and has a no-arg constructor that pre-populates this map with initial values.

I am stuck at the first task - how to extend the LinkedHashMap in such a way that instead of generic arguments it accepts  only?

I tried this, (not working)

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyMenu<String, String> extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> {


    public MyMenu(){
        this.put("index.jsp", "Home Page");
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to complete your last sentence. Anyways, it won't matter, unless you show some code you might have tried.

Comment: Extending LinkedHashMap is almost certainly a bad solution. You can use its parameterized form or use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: I would not have problem with composition but then I would need a getter method to getMap() from my object. I wanted my object to be a HashMap so it would be easier to use from jsp with jstl

Comment: i agree with @dystroy.  we use a utility method with varargs to initialize a map with initial values.

Comment: You would not necessarily need a getter to get the `Map` in a composition model.  You could implement the `Map` interface and just delegate to your...delegate...

Comment: Can someone maybe post a good link that explains why composition is better than extending HashMap? I don't see a problem with extending it in my particular case - I need to store map of jsp page to the page title so that I can dymanically create navigation menu in JSP

Comment: Why not just write a static factory method that creates a `LinkedHashMap`, puts the desired elements into it, and returns a result?  No need for a fragile subclass here.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Because I want my class to behave like a bean, so I can use it from jsp page with <jsp:useBean.... it will be easy when my class has no-argument constructor. with wrapper factory class it will probably not be so easy to use it from jsp. I'm just a beginner...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you need is:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyMenu extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> {

    public MyMenu(){
        this.put("index.jsp", "Home Page");
    }
}
```

Remove `<String, String>` from your class name and it will work. You are creating a class which is extending `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` so your class is already a `Map` which takes `String` as a key and `String` as a value. If you want to create your own generic class then you have to do like this:

Create a class for e.g.:

```
public class MyMenu<K, V> { ... }
```

and then extend that class:

```
public class SomeMyMenu extends MyMenu<String, String> { ... }
```

In that case you will have to specify the key and value for your class in order for `SomeMyMenu` class use the key and value as `String`. You can read more about generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

But more efficient way to do what you want is to create some final class and declare the map in it like this:

```
public static final LinkedHashMap<String, String> MAP = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("index.jsp", "Home Page");
}};
```

And to get the values from your map use:

```
SomeClass.MAP.get("Some Key");
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I still would like to get explanation why I don't need <String, String> after MyMenu? I am learning working with generics in Java and any good explanation is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

If your struggle, as you describe, is just with the declaration, then I would try something like:

```
class MyCustomizedMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like below:

```
   public class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap<String,String>{
```

Answer (score 2):

Composition is a better solution than inheritance in your case:

```
class MyProperties implements Map<String, String> {

    private Map<String, String> delegatee = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    // ... delegate your methods to delegatee
}
```

Comment: Composition is almost always better than inheritance. +1

Comment: But not "always"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using JDK 1.5 or higher, you can use generics and create a LinkedHashMap that stores String keys and String values and initialize it as follows:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>()
{
    {
        put("abc", "xyz");
        ...
    };
}
```